# Export each sheet to a separate csv file

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, vba

I need to programmaticaly via a VBA/VBS script export all worksheets (4 in total and I know the names) to worksheet named csv files in the same folder, without loading excel and running the macro manually.

Ideally the script would take in the source filepath/filename.xls and the export filepath as command line arguments.

I have read many Excel VBA scripts for doing just that within Excel and I have seen some for loading an excel workbook to export the first sheet. However when I try to blend the two I get this error:

> (1,12) Expected End of Statement

```
Dim source As Workbook
Set source = Application.Workbooks.Open(WScript.Arguments.Item(0), ReadOnly:=True)
For Each sheet In source.Sheets
.SaveAs Filename:= WScript.Arguments.Item(1) & Source.Sheets.Name, FileFormat:=xlCSV
Next sheet
wb.Close
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your code so others can help debug it. Showing effort is always appreciated (and expected).

Comment: Apologies, I felt I was probably way off with the code I was trying to execute so didn't wish to submit. As I said I have a similar vba working that does get the first sheet, this code is a simple amalgamation with some other in workbook script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) to run this code would look something like this.

1. The vbs file can be executed from the commandline
2. The folder name is redundant as if the file exists (the FSO object tests for this) then the folder it resides in must also exist
3. The code automates Excel to separate the sheets

two key points to note compared to your VBA above

- you can't Dim a vbs object as a string, Workbook etc (hence your initial error). You can only Dim them
- you can't used a named constant such as `xlCSV` in vbscript, hence the use of 6 below as the CSV format

  ```
  Dim strFilename  
  Dim objFSO  
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")  
  strFilename = "C:\temp\test.xlsx"  
  If objFSO.fileexists(strFilename) Then  
    Call Writefile(strFilename)  
  Else  
    wscript.echo "no such file!"  
  End If  
  Set objFSO = Nothing  

  Sub Writefile(ByVal strFilename)  
  Dim objExcel  
  Dim objWB  
  Dim objws  

  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  
  Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFilename)  

  For Each objws In objWB.Sheets  
    objws.Copy  
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs objWB.Path & "\" & objws.Name & ".csv", 6  
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False  
  Next 

  objWB.Close False  
  objExcel.Quit  
  Set objExcel = Nothing  
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: That is just what I required, many thanks, a very good explanation and thank you for letting me know where I was going wrong. I have learnt something here.

Comment: Appreciate if this can be changed to read any filename instead of hardcoding the filename.

Answer (score -1):

To get you started:

Given an Excel workbook containing a sheet Demo like

```
-------------------------------
SELECT * FROM Demo
-------------------------------
|F1|F2 |F3        |F4        |
| 1|1.1|12/10/2011|text elm 1|
| 2|2.2|12/11/2011|text elm 2|
| 3|4.4|12/12/2011|text elm 3|
-------------------------------
```

and an ADODB.Connection with a ConnectionString like:

```
Provider=MSDASQL.1;Extended Properties="DBQ=<FullPathToYourXls>;Driver={Microsoft
 Excel Driver (*.xls)};
```

all you need to .Execute is a SELECT INTO statement like

```
SELECT * INTO [Demo.csv] IN '<PathToYourCsvFolder>' 'Text;' FROM Demo
```

to get:

```
type ..\data\ExcelCsv2\Demo.csv
"F1";"F2";"F3";"F4"
1;1,10;10.12.2011 00:00:00;"text elm 1"
2;2,20;11.12.2011 00:00:00;"text elm 2"
3;4,40;12.12.2011 00:00:00;"text elm 3"
```

(german locale)

The SELECT INTO statement will create the appropriate section

```
[Demo.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
CharacterSet=1252
Format=Delimited(;)
Col1=F1 Integer
Col2=F2 Float
Col3=F3 Date
Col4=F4 Char Width 50
```

in the schema.ini file automagically.

Comment: Many thanks Ekkehard however I am not using a conventional language the most I can achieve from my environment is to call a vbs script while passing the required parameters. However if the connection string can be run in VBA then I may be able to switch around the xls file to which I can maintain a connection.

Comment: Also I do not see how your example works with multiple sheets in a workbook, am I missing something?