# How to make more than one csv file from xls file?

Tags: excel, csv, vba

- I have Excel file with 12 sheets.
- When trying to save the file as CSV file (`Save As ...`), I had to do that 12 times manually (for every sheet separately).

Is there a way not to do that manually or to do that manually in one step?

Comment: And where can I put the code?

Answer (score 3):

I have provided a [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) version of my [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) code from [Export each sheet to a separate csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434994/export-all-worksheets-in-a-known-excel-file-to-csvs-programatically-using-a-vbs)

It saves individual sheets to the same path as the host workbook (`ActiveWorkbook`) with the name of each sheet tab being used from the host workbook for the filename(s).

```
Sub SaveAsCSV()
Dim objWB As Workbook
Dim objws As Worksheet

Set objWB = ActiveWorkbook

If Len(objWB.Path) = 0 Then
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name & " is not saved. Please save file then re-run this code", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

For Each objws In objWB.Sheets
  objws.Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs objWB.Path & "\" & objws.Name & ".csv", xlCSV
  ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```