# Cycle a vba function through all workbooks in a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I want to cycle through all workbooks in a folder, extract worksheets named "Sheet Name", and save them as .csv files with the name of the file from which they originated. What's quick way to do this?

Example of vba function in question:

```
Sub Sheet_SaveAs()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Sheets("Sheet Name").Copy  
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook       
  With wb
  .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.name, FileFormat:=xlCSV
  '.Close False
  End With
End Sub
```

Many thanks for looking

EDIT: Not a duplicate because I am working on extracting sheets from multiple workbooks, and not multiple worksheets from a single workbook.

EDIT2: thank you, everyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving excel worksheet to CSV files with filename+worksheet name using VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551353/saving-excel-worksheet-to-csv-files-with-filenameworksheet-name-using-vb)

Comment: I think you're right, although I tried the code marked as answer, and I get an error that my file may be corrupted or read only, which I wasn't getting previously.

Comment: •you can't used a named constant such as xlCSV in vbscript, hence the use of 6 below as the CSV format. ~For Each objws In objWB.Sheets  
  objws.Copy  
  objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs objWB.Path & "\" & objws.Name & ".csv", 6  
  objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False  
Next~ and then try again

Comment: please try @brettdj code in the post <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434994/export-each-sheet-to-a-separate-csv-file> I have tested it earlier, it works.

Comment: The solutions you're referring me to don't work on copying across multiple workbooks in a folder; I think they are for multiple worksheets in a workbook.

Comment: Please go through this post there are other solutions which should work in your case. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075/save-each-sheet-in-a-workbook-to-separate-csv-files>

Comment: Please see the abstracts from a program by @HigherAbstraction  "Here is one that will give you a visual file chooser to pick the folder you want to save the files to and also lets you choose the CSV delimiter (I use pipes '|' because my fields contain commas and I don't want to deal with quotes):" This is a highly voted post. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075/save-each-sheet-in-a-workbook-to-separate-csv-files> .

Comment: You will have to use recursive procedure. Another 2 links are given here.<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645347/loop-through-all-subfolders-using-vba> and <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245712/cycle-through-sub-folders-and-files-in-a-user-specified-root-directory> You may have to adopt the code with slight modification to match with your requirements. After putting efforts, if you are not able to get it through, then point out the code line or code portion you are having difficulties. I can assure people here are willing to help you fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

Change this path to suit your folder

```
strFolder = "c:\temp"
```

*code*

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFile As String

    strFolder = "c:\temp"
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.xls*")

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
     Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & "\" & strFile)
     Set ws = Nothing
     On Error Resume Next
     Set ws = Wb.Sheets("Sheet Name")
     On Error GoTo 0
     If Not ws Is Nothing Then ws.SaveAs Left$(Wb.FullName, InStrRev(Wb.FullName, ".")) & "csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
     Wb.Close False
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

     With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```