# Save as text file macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to export a particular sheet in my excel workbook to a tab delimited text file using a macro. My workbook is macro enabled. I have tried to start recording and save the file. When I stop the recording, I am able to see the macro created. Upon closing the xlsm file and opening it again, I do not see the recorded macro in the file anymore.

Any help would be much appreciated in this.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551353/saving-excel-worksheet-to-csv-files-with-filenameworksheet-name-using-vb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export each sheet to a separate csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434994/export-each-sheet-to-a-separate-csv-file)